# Update SQL query within php

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to update my phpmyadmin table using php variables. But it doesn't seem to be working I am ok Inserting data. Can anyone point me in the write direction as too where i am going wrong.

```
  $query = "UPDATE set DestName = '$DestName', DestRating = '$DestRating', DestImage = '$DestImage' WHERE DestID = '$id'";
```

Comment: have you not spent time reading the manuals and its syntaxes?

Comment: My previous comment should have been `UPDATE tablename SET... `

Comment: @Fred-ii- Which manuals?

Comment: on mysql.com and tutorials

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the table name: `UPDATE FOO SET ...` (where `FOO` is the tables name).